# Android XML Themes VS Styling

Tags: android, styles, themes, basic4android

I've perused ALL of the questions here and countless tutorials on Styling and Themes for Android.  The odd hierarchy between Themes and Styles is still a mystery to me.

My Manifest calls out this "Style"  (android:theme, "@style/rforderstyle") [this is formatted from the manifest editor in Basic4Android] (*not my choice but its what I have to use.*).. however the manifest is still accessible should I need to.
I mention this because I've noticed that you can style a specific activity. I actually don't see a way to force have multiple "wigets" have their own "theme" while they all exist on the same activity.

Please advise if so then I my need to make my "little creations" as whatever "fragment" or "wigets".
What I'm attempting is a windows mobile app type form with a ton of User controls on it..so this set at the bottom happens to use a mid sized black text font.. but the control over here in the right upper is a different text size and color  on & On & on ...

So regarding the style xml file,   I've read that,,, its important that,,,, my parent be some all encompassing Android theme and I override individual "properties" in this section::

Could that mean that although I'm concerned with text size, since I have labels and editcontrols present the absence of a "parent" style that addresses these will cause me an error as I attempt to use this referenced parent style ??
How does a theme get into this mix...?

```
    <resources>
      <style name="rforderstyle" parent="@android:style/TextAppearance">>
      <item name="android:textSize"> 21.0dp</item>
      <item name="android:typeface">serif</item>
      <item name="android:textColor">#FF9900 </item><!--#00FF00-->
      </style>
    </resources>
```

This is oddly confusing because the best examples reference layout files for the views but I don't really have layout files in Basic4Android I'm programmatically creating all of these views.  If I don't need the depth of theme **and** style then fine but ...is the manifest supposed to point to a Style or a theme?